# JavaFX, JavaScript console logging, and Frameworks (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, java, javafx

I'm working on an application that is basically a self-contained webapp. Jetty back end that communicates with an HTML/JS front end via RESTful Ajax calls, with the front end being within a JavaFX WebEngine.

Anyway, I'm using Vue.js with this project. I've redirected the console logging using the same approach I've read about several times (Please note I'm using Kotlin for the back end):

```
class JavaBridge {

    fun log(text: String){
        AppLogger.webConsole.debug(text)
    }

}

//Other code here...

val window = engine.executeScript("window") as JSObject
val bridge = JavaBridge()
window.setMember("java", bridge)
engine.executeScript("""
console.log = function(message){
    java.log(message);
}
""")
```

So, here is an example of my issue, with some sample JavaScript:

```
console.log('This will print to the logs');
new Vue({
    el: '#element',
    methods: {
        doSomething: function(){
            console.log('This will do nothing');
        }
    }
});
```

As the code sample suggests, any calls to console.log() from within the Vue object don't work. I finally wrapped the call in a TryCatch block, and this was the exception message i got:

```
"java.log is not a function. (In 'java.log(message)', 'java.log' is undefined)"
```

I'm new to JavaFX, I'm just using it as a wrapper for the front end code. Why is this happening, and what I need to do to fix it?

### Edit

Added the code where the JavaBridge object is added to "window".

Comment: What is your definition of `java.log`? The `java` variable is an instance of  `JavaBridge`? Add more code info please.

Comment: Just did that. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it, it works just fine for me.